# Goodness of fit

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, special-functions, nonlinear

I want to evaluate the goodness of two sets or more fitting parameters, using Rsquared and RMSE (root mean square error), Then how to code?)

```
 data = {
         {43.68, 1.}, {206.42, 0.76}, {398.11, 0.58},
         {1019.47, 0.42}, {1910.44, 0.33}, {2964.39, 0.26}, 
         {4116.84, 0.22}, {5318.17, 0.19}, {6505.9, 0.16}, 
         {7709.48, 0.15}, {8827.55, 0.13}, {9984.18, 0.12}, 
         {11015.08, 0.11}};

model = Sum[4/((2*k + 1)*Pi)*1(*c0*)* MittagLefflerE[β, ((-d)* (2*k + 1)^2*π^2*t^β)]*
Sin[(2*k + 1)*Pi*1/2], {k, 0, 10}];

M = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {{β, 0.7}, {d, 0.0002}}, t];

Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],  Plot[M // Normal, {t, 
data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]},PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

In the above case, I use the fitting parameter set `{β=0.7,d=0.0002}` and  get the fitting curve shown below.

[image: {β=0.7,d=0.0002} fitting]

In another case, I use the fitting parameter set `{β=0.71,d=0.0029}` and get the fitting curve shown below.

[image: {β=0.71,d=0.0029} fitting]

The two curves are quite similar, I need to use quantity criteria like  "R-squared" and RMSE to assess the goodness of fitness. I searched in the documentation, and it seems no RMSE property is available.

**How can I get the "RMSE" and "R-squared" from my FittedModel ?**

Comment: [`RootMeanSquare`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootMeanSquare.html) is built-in. In **Application** section an example calculating RMSE of fitting result is shown.

Comment: I don't think RootMeanSquare and RMSE are the same thing.

Comment: Your change of the initial estimates for the parameters does not appreciably change the "BestFitParameters" for the model `{β -> 0.59542, d -> 0.00204182}`

Comment: @BobHanlon ，As an MMA beginner, I don't know how to get the 'BestFitParameters'. That's a huge problem upset me a lot.

Comment: As shown in the documentation, `M[“BestFitParameters”]`

Comment: @Stan, let me know if my answer helps.

Comment: @rhermans, thanks. It helps me a lot, but  I need some time to digest the new commands.

Comment: As mentioned above, `RootMeanSquare` can be used to calculate RMSE, and an example can be found in **Application** section of document, please check it carefully. Also, by searching RMSE in this site, one can find more examples: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=rmse

Comment: What does "in another case" mean?  Same model but different starting values?  If so, then R-squared is inappropriate (and at best useless) to make a comparison.

Comment: I wonder if the term `Sin[2*k+1)*Pi*1/2]` is really necessary as it is equivalent to `(-1)^k`.

Comment: You might consider using $AIC_c$ to determine how many terms are needed in your model.  Currently you have 11 terms (`{k, 0, 10}`) but using $AIC_c$ suggests that just 2 terms is more appropriate.  In other words, using 11 terms is overfitting.

Comment: @BobHanlon，You mean, even though the values of fitting parameters are changed, the `NonlinearModelFit` gives the Best Fit Parameters ` {β -> 0.59542, d -> 0.00204182} ` for my form? so the starting values of fitting parameters doesn't matter.

Comment: @BobHanlon, so the key problem is how to find a good starting value. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Both of your initial estimates cause the fit to converge to the same solution. The solution is the model evaluated with the "BestFitParameters". Bad initial estimates could converge to some other result but that result would be a demonstrably bad fit.

Comment: @JimB, you bet. Despite the starting value, all the fittings use the best fit parameters.

Comment: @BobHanlon, how to find the proper initial estimates is a trouble.  Do you remember, we have discussed the solution for two unknown variables of three equations? I want to find a reasonable starting value by that way.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [this page](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/rmse-root-mean-square-error/), definition of *Root Mean Square Error* (RMSE) is:

[image]

where

$f$ = forecasts (expected values or unknown results)

$o$ = observed values (known results)

$Σ$ = summation (“add up”)

$({{z_f}_i} – {{z_o}_i})^2$ = differences, squared

$N$ = sample size.

Now that you have your [FittedModel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FittedModel.html) `M` given by [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), you can extract the properties like this

```
M["BestFitParameters"]
(* {β->0.59542,d->0.00204182} *)
```

It's obvious ${{z_f}_i} – {{z_o}_i}$ stands for residuals. Therefore, if you want the RMSE, you do

```
RootMeanSquare@M["FitResiduals"]
```

Also, the `"RSquared"` property is [described in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html?view=all#:%7E:text=Bayesian%20Information%20Criterion-,%22RSquared%22,-coefficient%20of%20determination)

```
M["RSquared"]
```

Also of interest

```
M["EstimatedVariance"]
```

And to assess the goodness of fit I recommend looking into the [`"AIC"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html?view=all#:%7E:text=of%20model%20parameters-,%22AIC%22,-Akaike%20Information%20Criterion) property that provides the [Akaike Information Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)

Comment: `StandardDeviation@M["FitResiduals"]` isn't correct. Check the formula _Barnston, 1992_ on that page. See also my comments above.

Comment: @xzczd I don't see it, if mine is wrong, please offer the correct explanation.

Comment: Well, just search _1992_ on that web page by e.g. pressing Ctrl+F, you'll see the formula is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ocd.png But definition of `StandardDeviation` is `Sqrt@Total[(list-Mean[list])^2]/(Length[list]-1)`.

Comment: @xzczd, I thought that if you have the actual mean, then you use the population standard deviation, and divide by $n$. If you come up with an estimate of the mean based on averaging the data, then you should use the sample standard deviation, and divide by $n-1$. Is that not correct?

Comment: …It's not merely $N$ v.s. $N-1$, notice the difference in the formula is calculated by $z_{f_i}-z_{o_i}$ where $z_{o_i}$ is the observed value, not the mean value.

Comment: @xzczd I suggest that you either edit my answer or provide an answer yourself.

Comment: OK, done. Hopefully it's a bit clearer.